# Intel@ Atom'" x5-Z8350 CPU with Linux Mint crashes

Tags: linux

I have this spec in my mini PC -
Processor Intel@ Atom'" x5-Z8350 CPU 1.44GHz x 4

Memory 3.3 GiB

Hard Drives 41.6 GB

Graphics Card Intel Corporation Atom/Celeron/Pentium Processor x5-E8000/J3xxx/ N3xxx Integrated Graphics Controller

I installed Linux mint XFCE - and the first thing - I tried to see a simple youtube on firefox
it crashed right away. (white screen)
after that tried to open the system manager - it crashed again. (purple screen)

Is the Linux mint XFCE too heavy for my PC?

What can I do?

Thanks!

Comment: 3.3GB of RAM? Are you sure? The ARK page suggests the max is 2GB.

Comment: I’ve had lots of problems with the graphics output on an even lower-performance CPU (N3150). Unfortunately, there are lots of bugs in the Intel graphics driver for these low-end integrated GPUs.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible your system is under configured for running linux.
On the passmark benchmark site it is listed at 908 units (480 single core).

https://www.cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=Intel+Atom+x5-Z8350+%40+1.44GHz

This is quite "weak" compared  more modern cpus.  I have gotten Puppy linux
to work on cpus this small (HP Net book with 2G memory)
But it would not work with video (Google meet specifically) Stuttered alot.
So this is consistent with your results

https://puppylinux-woof-ce.github.io/
the Ubuntu Focal 64 is the version I tried.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Mint is very heavy for atom. Try AntiX or Puppy linux. And play youtube trough VLC